# How to compute the Laurent series of $(1+D/x)^{6/5}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, binomial-theorem, laurent-series

$(1+D/x)^{6/5}$

How do we compute the Laurent seires when we have fractional power like this and the iside is negative power? Where should I expand the seires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding Lubin's answer:

$(1+D/x)^{6/5}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{6/5}{n}\frac{D^n}{x^n}
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{6/5}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac65-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(6-5k)}{5^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(5k-6)}{5^nn!}\\
\end{array}
$

You can play around
with this 
to try to get
a nicer looking result
like you get for
$\binom{1/2}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you’re looking for a series in nonpositive powers of $x$. Assuming that, I say: write out the series for $(1+Dx)^{6/5}$ — you can use the Binomial expansion — and then just change the sign on all exponents of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as finding, around $y=0$, the Taylor series of
$$f(y)=(1+y)^{\frac 65}\qquad \text{with} \qquad y=\frac Dx$$ and the binomial series is the power series
$$(1+y)^\alpha= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{n}y^n$$ where
$$\binom{\alpha}{n} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\alpha-k+1}k = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}$$